# How do I optimize the display of blocks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have more than 550 blocks of content loaded on my page and it takes a long time to load the page, and even more so on my phone over wi-fi. I tried to output 25 blocks using WordPress pagination and it worked. But there was a problem: the filter only looked for blocks on the open page.

It turns out that he was looking for only 25 blocks, and all the other blocks he did not take, because they were on other pages. And I have a question: how to optimize page loading and display not all 550 blocks at once, but so that the filter searches from all available ones.

I thought to do it somehow with the help of scripts can you?  Here by the way is the filter script itself:

```
  function applyFilters() {
  
     var direction1 = $("#direction1").val();
     var level1 = $("#level1").val();
     var universities = $("#universities").val();
     var language = $("#language").val();
     var program = $("#program").val();
    
     var selector = "#card-wrapper-first ." + direction1 + "." + level1 + "." + program + "." + language + "." + universities;


    $('#card-wrapper-first .card-item').hide();
    $(selector).show();
}
```

It takes the class of the selected options and compares them with the classes on the blocks after clicking the "Select" button.

Comment: If you want it all in one page then use ajax to retrieve data and only render what is needed by filter(s). You can load all the content by ajax or set up back end to receive filter params and send what you need. Lots of ways to filter content in wordpress

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what I need to do?